# Appending HTML inputs using JavaScript gives "undefined" value

Tags: javascript, append, insertadjacenthtml

I have a small code trying to append values using HTML inputs to the same document.

```html
<h2 id="myh"> Header</h2>
<input type="text" id="text">
<button onclick="func()">Append</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var child = document.getElementById("text").value;

  function func() {
    var h = document.getElementById('myh');
    h.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<p> New Para' + toString(child) + '</p>');
  }
</script>
```

the variable `child` dose not take the text value from the input, which outputted as `undefined'

*image 1: typed `Test`*

[image]

*Image 2: Clicked the Button*

[image]

how to get the value form the input as New ParaTest?

### Code Edited using the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `toString()` method, remove it.

Get the reference of element in the `child` variable and get the `value` the `func()`

```js
var child = document.getElementById("text");

function func() {
  var h = document.getElementById('myh');
  h.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<p> New Para: ' + child.value + '</p>');
}
```

```html
<h2 id="myh"> Header</h2>
<input type="text" id="text">
<button onclick="func()">Append</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

`child` variable needs to assign inside func function and don't need `toString()`
try this

```js
function func(){
   var h = document.getElementById('myh');
   let child = document.getElementById("text").value;
   h.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend','<p> New Para' + child + '</p>');
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <h2 id="myh"> Header</h2>
    <input type="text" id="text">
    <button onclick="func()">Append</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your variable should be global. Try taking it inside the function and then check it.

```
    function func(){
        var child = document.getElementById("text").value;
        var h = document.getElementById('myh');
        h.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend','<p> New Para' + toString(child) + '</p>');
    }
```